# Why does this env object keep growing in size ?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, web-crawler, heap-memory, crawler4j

I have been working on a web crawler for some time now, the idea is simple, I have a SQL table containing a list of websites, I have many threads fetching the first website from the table and deleting it, then crawling it ( in a heap like manner).

Code is a bit too long so I'm gonna try and delete some parts of it :

```
 while(true){
    if(!stopped){  
        System.gc();

        Statement stmt;
        String scanned = "scanned";
        if (!scan)scanned = "crawled";
        Connection connection = null;
            try {
            connection = Utils.getConnection();
            } catch (Exception e1) {

            connection.close();
            e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String name;
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = null;
            boolean next;
            do {
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("select url from websites where "+scanned+" = -1");
            next = rs.next();
            } while (next && Utils.inBlackList(rs.getString(1)));


            if(next){
            name = rs.getString(1);
            stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE websites SET "+scanned+" = 1 where url = '"+Utils.stripDomainName(name)+"'");
            String backup_name = name;
            name = Utils.checkUrl(name);
            System.out.println(scanned + " of the website :  " + name +" just started by the Thread : " + num);

            // And here is the important part, I think

            CrawlConfig config = new CrawlConfig();
            String ts = Utils.getTime();
            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            String SessionId = new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
            String crawlStorageFolder = "tmp/temp_storageadmin"+SessionId;
            config.setCrawlStorageFolder(crawlStorageFolder);

            config.setPolitenessDelay(Main.POLITENESS_DELAY);
            config.setMaxDepthOfCrawling(Main.MAX_DEPTH_OF_CRAWLING);
            config.setMaxPagesToFetch(Main.MAX_PAGES_TO_FETCH);
            config.setResumableCrawling(Main.RESUMABLE_CRAWLING);
            int numberOfCrawlers = Main.NUMBER_OF_CRAWLERS;
            PageFetcher pageFetcher = new PageFetcher(config);
            RobotstxtConfig robotstxtConfig = new RobotstxtConfig();
            RobotstxtServer robotstxtServer = new RobotstxtServer(robotstxtConfig, pageFetcher);

            try {
                  controller = new CrawlerController(config, pageFetcher, robotstxtServer);
                  controller.addSeed(name);
                  controller.setSeeed(name);
                  controller.setTimestamp(ts);
                  controller.setSessiiid("admin"+num+scan);

                  //Main.crawls.addCrawl("admin"+num+scan, new Crawl(name,"admin"+num+scan,ts));
                 stmt.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM tempCrawl WHERE SessionID = '"+"admin"+num+scan+"'");
                  if (!scan){
                     // Main.crawls.getCrawl("admin"+num+scan).setCrawl(true);

                     stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tempCrawl (SessionID, url, ts, done, crawledpages, misspelled, english, proper, scan, crawl )"
                        + " VALUES ( '"+"admin"+num+scan+"', '"+name+"', '"+ts+"', false, 0, 0, true, false, "+false+" , "+true+"  )");
                  }else{
                      //Main.crawls.getCrawl("admin"+num+scan).setScan(true);

                     stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tempCrawl (SessionID, url, ts, done, crawledpages, misspelled, english, proper, scan, crawl )"
                        + " VALUES ( '"+"admin"+num+scan+"', '"+name+"', '"+ts+"', false, 0, 0, true, false, "+true+" , "+false+"  )");
                  }
                  connection.close();
                  controller.start_auto(Crawler.class, numberOfCrawlers, false, scan,num);

            } catch(Exception e){
                      rs.close();
                      connection.close();
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }else{
               rs.close();
               connection.close();
            }  






        //CrawlerController.start_auto(scan, num);

        if (stopping){
        stopped = true;
        stopping = false;
        }
    }}
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As you can see, each time I'm creating a crawlerController, and crawling a website and so on.

The problem here is that jvm memory heap keeps increasing in size considerably. After profiling the application using yourKit Java profiler I located the memory leak in the following lines of code :

[yourKit profiling screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGygw.jpg)

Now this is the exact line from where the memory leak starts, this env variable seems to take up too much space, and keeps increasing after each operation, whereas the operations are independent.

```
    Environment env = new Environment(envHome, envConfig);
```

I don't really know what this variable does, and how I could fix it, one more thing, I did alter the crawlController source code, I thought that might be relevant.

Comment: a tiny hint: you should use private methods to organize the code within the loop for increased clarity. It will help you and other programmers that might want to understand or maintain your code :)

Comment: Thanks ! I just have the bad habit of writing it all down, then organize it only once it's working, as I said, bad habit.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using `crawler4j` as crawling-framework.

Everytime you create a `crawl controller` you instantiate a new `frontier`, which is shared between the crawler threads to manage the queue of URLs to crawl. Moreover, a so called 'docIdServer' is created, which has the responsiblity to manage if an incoming URL (e.g. website) has already been processed in this crawl.

This `frontier` and the `docIdServer` are based on an in-memory database, in which the [environment](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/java/com/sleepycat/je/Environment.html) is responsible for caching, locking, logging and transaction. For that reason, this variable will grow over time.

If you set resumable crawling to `true`, the database will operate in file-mode and there it will grow slower.